Splashscreen api crashes on android 12
My android app crashes due to new splashscreen api implementation after releasing to playstore. Some users have experienced crashes in splashscreen issue as per the crashlytics
I have tested in android device api level versions 12, 13 , 14 splashscreen working fine and not able to reproduce the crash.
Crash details:
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullpointerException

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.window.peekDecorview()' on a null object reference

android.app.ActivityThread.handleAttachSplashScreenView (ActivityThread.java:4634)

android.app.servertransaction.TransferSplashScreenViewStateItem.execute(TransferSplashScreenViewStateItem.java:40)

android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)

android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)

android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)

android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2685)

android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)

android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)

android.os.Loop(Looper.java:319)

android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8919)

Java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)

com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578)

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)

Crashlytics screenshot:


Please edit your question and add the entire error message as text and not as an image.

Hi @AlexMamo update the error msg as text

It's hard to tell without some more information on what devices the
crash is happening and their Android Version.
But it seems like you have a migration problem to the new SplashScreen Api.
You can see complete instructions here: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen/migrate
According to the Window class definition:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window
peekDecorView() returns the current DecorView of the window or null.
the DecorView is what holds the background of your window which in your case is the SplashScreen Window. So I would guess some of your users have trouble setting the Drawable Icon background which causes your DecorView to become null.

thanks. I have attached Screenshot of crashlytic in description of question please look it int it. I  have tested in android 12, 13, 14 devices its working fine. We are not able to reproduce the issue.

Issue happened android 14 version, GalaxyS22 device as per the crashlytics
